# How to force empty elements to appear for JAXB generated XML (for Strings, Longs, and Integers types)

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a java model class that I need to unmarshall to xml. I am using jaxb. The problem I am facing is that I need empty elements to appear in the output, but by default it seems they do not. Here is sample of my model (with many fewer fields):

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "model:MyModel")
public class MyModel {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;


    public MyModel() {}

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "model:field1")
    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "model:field2")
    public void setField2(String field2) {
       this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public String getField3() {
        return field3;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "model:field3")
    public void setField3(String field3) {
        this.field3 = field3;
    }
}
```

, and for example purposes, I simple app like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class MyApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
            myModel.setField1("cat");
            myModel.setField3("dog");

            JAXBContext jc = null;
            try {
                jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyModel.class);
                Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                marshaller.marshal(myModel, System.out);
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

As written, the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model:MyModel>
    <model:field1>cat</model:field1>
    <model:field3>dog</model:field3>
</model:MyModel>
```

, but I need the empty element for the null field2. Also, my model actually has a couple of dozen fields, a combination of Strings, Longs, and Integers, any one of which can be null.

So I am looking for a solution that provides empty element for any of these fields. I'd also consider alternatives to JAXB if anyone has alternatives that will support what I need. I would be grateful for any ideas. Thank you

Comment: Does adding `, rquired=true` to your `@XMLElement` annotation provide the desired behaviour?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I tried adding required=true. It had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use Jackson for xml rather than JAXB. It, by default, handled my base situation (requiring empty elements for null fields). But also, Jackson for xml essentially is just Jackson for JSON with a few additional annotations and other capabilties, so it is more portable between JSON and XML.

So, here is sample model:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonRootName("model:MyJacksonModel")
public class MyJacksonModel {
    @JsonProperty("model:field1")
    private String field1;
    @JsonProperty("model:field2")
    private String field2;
    @JsonProperty("model:field3")
    private String field3;

    public MyJacksonModel() { }

    public String getField1() { return field1;}
    public void setField1(String field1) { this.field1 = field1;}
    public String getField2() { return field2;}
    public void setField2(String field2) { this.field2 = field2;  }
    public String getField3() { return field3;}
    public void setField3(String field3) { this.field3 = field3; }
}
```

, and simple app:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import mil.dia.mars.de.model.MyJacksonModel;

public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyJacksonModel myJModel = new MyJacksonModel();
        myJModel.setField1("cat");
        myJModel.setField3("dog");

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        String jString = "";
        try {
            jString = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(myJModel);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(jString);
    }
}
```

, and output:

```
<model:MyJacksonModel>
    <model:field1>cat</model:field1>
    <model:field2/>
    <model:field3>dog</model:field3>
</model:MyJacksonModel>
```